# Compilation issue : Incompatibility of Swift versions between two packages

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have to edit an iOS app that was developed by someone who is no longer in the project.

He gave me the source code of the application but I can not compile it. I was using xcode.

The iOS project contain 2 packages :

- MAIN : contain the application written in Swift 3.0.1
- PODS : contain the library used by the application written in swift 2.3

I changed the "Build settings" of MAIN.xcodeproj :
in "Swift Compiler - Version" I changed the "Use Legacy Swift Language version" to "No"
in PODS.xcodeproj I put this setting to "Yes"

When I try to build the project, I get the following problem :

```
Contact.swift:10:8: Module compiled with Swift 2.3 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.1: JSONCodable.swiftmodule
```

When I follow the advise from other posts in stackoverflow, that is to change "Swift Compiler - Version" I changed the "Use Legacy Swift Language version"
of MAIN.xcodeproj to "Yes", I get a lot of errors of compatibility such as :

```
/MAIN/Model/Data.swift:55:1: Type 'Data' does not conform to protocol 'Storable'
```

I tried all the possible value for "Use Legacy Swift Language version" without succes. 
I also tried to add a ".swift-version" file at the root folder that just contain "3.0.1" but it did not worked.

I tried to add in my podfile this line :

```
 config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0.1'
```

But it didn't worked neither.

I tried to re-install cocaopods but nothing changed.

How can I import my libraries written in swift 2.3 to my project written in swift 3.0.1 ?

Thank you

Comment: you need to reinstall pods

Comment: I reinstall it several time without success, I tried to force the swift version in the podfile but it did not worked neither

Comment: follow this steps:go to Edit >> Convert >> CurrentSwiftSyntax

Comment: I tried it but I have a lot of things to modify manually. I will try to make all the changes if it is the only way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the only solution is to convert code of your Pods from 2.3 to 3.0 and then modify the things that did not changed automatically by xcode.
Maybe you could force your pod version in the podfile with :

> pod'~> 3.0.1'

and then re-install the pods with

```
 pod install
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift does not yet support using a package compiled in one version of the language in an app compiled with a different version. You must rewrite one of them so they both use the same version.

This requires the swift ABI to be stable which was going to happen with swift version 4 but has now been delayed.

Comment: Yes but the project was compiled before, the app is already on the store.. So I think that I can compile it, unless the guy gave me the wrong sources..